# Reusing Same Spark Session causing multiple active Stages

Tags: apache-spark, caching

We have a large dataset of few million records and then processing subset in a sequence of Spark Transformations and Actions.
Each subset goes through same set of transformations and actions.
First step is to get data and persist it in Memory then do multiple operations and then unpersist the cache.
This is repeated almost 2000 times. After it has repeated 200-300 times we observe the the number of active stages are almost 3000 and keeps growing.
We are expecting that with each Unpersist the corresponding stages should go away but still the stages remain.

Looking for a solution to minimize Active stages so that Jobs can get completed.
Presently we are unable to process it to completion due to growing Active Stages.

```
Logic is somewhat as below:
SubRoutine1:
Received a listOfCustomer
Build a dataframe for the listOfCustomer based on certain common condition/criteria.
cache the dataframe

SubRoutine2:
Received listOfCustomer
For each customer from listOfCustomer:
    Get the cached dataframe
    apply few transformations and actions for this customer on this dataframe
    save the final result in some datastore
    if (customerIndex % 200 = 0) then refresh cache by calling SubRoutine1 again
```

Comment: What's the motivation for caching in this case?

Comment: Caching improves our Processing time by almost 10 times. We were able to process 20 Customers in an hr without Caching and with caching its almost 200